# What is the difference between if and else if

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int binary(int a[],int target,int l,int r); //return index , needs array, target  left index, right index
//goal: find if the number is in the array
int main(void)
{
    int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
    int target = get_int("number:");
    int l = 0;
    int r = 13;
    int index=binary(a,target,l,r);
    if(index>=0)
        printf("number %i is at index %i\n",target,index);
    else
        printf("not found\n");
}
int binary(int a[],int target,int l,int r)
{
    if(r<l)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    int mid=l+(r-l)/2;

    if(a[mid]==target)
    {
        return mid;
    }

    if(a[mid]<target)
    {
        return binary(a,target,mid+1,r);
    }
    if(a[mid]>target)
    {
        return binary(a,target,l,mid-1);
    }
}
```

Error when I compile this:

```
non-void function does not return a value in all control paths
[-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
```

However, I do not understand why I get this error message even though all my if statements have a return value.

However, when compared to the answer key, they used else if. I understand why they are right, but I do not understand why I am wrong though.

Comment: The compiler simply checks whether return exists in all paths, but does not judge/recognize whether the set of if conditions covers all possible patterns.

Comment: if you remove the last if it won't change your program behavior and it will compile

Comment: @seb although it would be more natural to make the case a[mid]==target the one where the routine exits normally. Testing it first adds overhead for a rare case.  Most times there will not be an exact match in a binary search so it should be last in line.  Worth trying it on a few other compilers - I reckon the odd one doing full dataflow analysis will recognise that the end of the routine is unreachable (and possibly say so). Although I suspect it requires non-trivial code to be present to trigger that warning.

Comment: "when compared to the answer key, they used else if." Without knowing the source, I would assume the main difference was that they had an `else` at the end instead of an `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies in your recursive calls to the binary function. Let's take a closer look:

```
if(a[mid]<target)
{
    return binary(a,target,l+1,r); // This should be mid+1 instead of l+1
}
if(a[mid]>target)
{
    return binary(a,target,l,r-1); // This should be mid-1 instead of r-1
}
```

In the recursive calls, you're not adjusting the boundaries properly. When you're searching the left half of the array, you should update r to mid - 1, not r - 1. Similarly, when searching the right half, you should update l to mid + 1, not l + 1.

Here's the corrected code:

```
if(a[mid]<target)
{
    return binary(a,target,mid+1,r);
}
if(a[mid]>target)
{
    return binary(a,target,l,mid-1);
}
```

Comment: This answer addresses the algorithm, but it doesn't answer the question. I've not (yet) downvoted, please [edit] and make that clear.

Comment: Agree with @Jabberwocky but a downvote seems harsh because it does address a real problem with the code in the question.

Comment: @JeremyP eventually didn't DV, but no UV from me either.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Ironically, this answer has been accepted even though it doesn't answer the question. Oh well.

Comment: @JeremyP yes, I saw that too...

Comment: @JeremyP is there an etiquette in accepting answers? well i found it useful as my code was wrong

Comment: @chunwai You can accept whatever answer you like, but it is be better if you accept an answer that addresses the question. This is because future people looking for an answer to the same question will not then be led astray.

Comment: @chunwai in this case, I don't think it is an issue, because the correct answer has quite a few upvotes.

Answer (score 6):

> i do not understand why i get this error message even though all my if statements have a return value.

Because, although it is obvious to you that one of those three `if` conditions must be true, the compiler can't work it out and thinks there is a possibility of not executing any of the blocks that return a value and thus falling out of the bottom of the function.

**Edit** missed a bit of the question.

> I understand why they are right, but i do not understand why i am wrong though.

In this case, you are not wrong. Because the statements executed inside the `if`s all return from the function, using `if` or `else if` is effectively the same.

To fix the error you are seeing, you need to omit the last condition because, by the time you get there, it is always true. You can do this:

```
    if(a[mid]==target)
    {
        return mid;
    }

    if(a[mid]<target)
    {
        return binary(a,target,l+1,r);
    }
    // a[mid]>target is guaranteed at this point
    return binary(a,target,l,r-1);
```

Or this:

```
    if(a[mid]==target)
    {
        return mid;
    }

    if(a[mid]<target)
    {
        return binary(a,target,l+1,r);
    }
    else
    {
        // a[mid]>target is guaranteed at this point
        return binary(a,target,l,r-1);
    }
```

Or this

```
    if(a[mid]==target)
    {
        return mid;
    }
    else if(a[mid]<target)
    {
        return binary(a,target,l+1,r);
    }
    else
    {
        // a[mid]>target is guaranteed at this point
        return binary(a,target,l,r-1);
    }
```

Personally, I go with the last one and I don't like the middle one because it mixes styles, but it's a matter of personal choice because they are all functionally the same.

**Edit 2** See also Priya's answer for the other bug in your code.